# Typeahead 0.11.1 not adding results from JSON

Tags: json, sinatra, typeahead

I'm trying to get Typeahead to add autocompletions from my JSON source, but there are no results being added.

**Some background info:** I've got Sinatra serving a JSON page which takes a query param, here's the code:

```
get '/search' do
    content_type :json
    Movie.search(params[:q], {
      fields: ["title^5"],
      limit: 10,
      load: false
    }).map(&:title).to_json
end
```

and it's working; here's an example result.

`/search?q=toy%20story` returns:

`["Toy Story"]`

My HTML input looks like this:

`<input id="search-box" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search for Movie Title" class="form-control" name="search">`

and my JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#search-box').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    limit: 10
  },
  {
    display: 'movie',
    source: function(query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
      $.get('/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query), function(data) {
        asyncResults(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

The results are showing up in the `console.log` as I type, and the Typeahead HTML entities are added, but with nothing in them and they're hidden.

Can anyone help? I've been stuck on this all day.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe it is `display: 'movie'` that is causing your problems. If you return an array of strings, i.e `["Toy Story"]` then you want to show the `value` of the array items :

```
display: 'value'
```

otherwise, if you work on an array of JSON items, like

```
[{ "title" : "2001: A Space Odyssey" } , { ... } ]
```

then `display` (or `displayKey`) should refer to the key / value pair you want to show in the dropdown :

```
display: 'title'
```